# MonoTouch.Dialog: No Default value

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am using the `BindingContext` to generate the table and don't want a default value chosen.

My Class has this field:

```
[RadioSelection ("Model:")] 
public int model = -1;
public IList<string> Model;
```

It is then added to the Root:

```
car = new AddCar () {
    Model = new List<string>(){"ES 250","ES 300","ES 330","ES 350"}
};
bc = new BindingContext (this, car, "Add Your Vehicle");
this.Root = bc.Root;
```

However the UI renders a selected value "ES 250" instead of a blank value:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a null or empty value to the beginning of your list.  Otherwise your only option is to modify MT.Dialog to behave the way you want.